Selenium On Newly Installed Ubuntu 24+ For Python 3.12 Will Not Run
For the past week I have been working on trying to get Selenium to function at all on a laptop that I freshly installed Ubuntu onto solely to work on personal projects. I was not finding any good solutions from Google search, most of the results were from 5+ years ago and even the newer examples did not function.
I have done basic troubleshooting. On top of that I went through the source code and had it pause and print out information to make sure they were correct. None of this has helped, not even getting the selenium manager executable, the top one from here and putting it into the spot that the selenium_manager.py script expects it to be.
I had a few different versions of testing files, put below:
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox() 

from selenium import webdriver

opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
drv = webdriver.firefox.service.Service()

drv.path = "/snap/bin/firefox"
opt.binary_location = '/snap/bin/firefox.geckodriver'

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt, service=drv)
browser.get("http://www.example.com")

The error messages I encountered when testing these and editing the source code were:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for firefox using Selenium Manager. selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary; /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /snap/bin/geckodriver/snap/bin/geckodriver selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /snap/bin/firefox/snap/bin/firefox


I finally found and answer in the closed issues section of Selenium's github repository https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13252#issuecomment-1845021270
posted by jn-chrn.
His working snippet is reproduced below.
import logging
import selenium.webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.firefox.service


logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

firefox_bin = "/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox"
firefoxdriver_bin = "/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/geckodriver"

options = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = firefox_bin

service = selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service(executable_path=firefoxdriver_bin)

browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

I can see that the path names are totally different, going deeper into the snap directories. jn-chrn sort of states why but doesn't go into full detail. The reason seems to be that the snap version of Firefox moved the raw executable off of PATH and the scripts that try to find it based just on the filenames don't work.
Running file on the two paths shows that selenium doesn't work with those symbolic links, they both just point to /usr/bin/snap/!
$ file /snap/bin/firefox
/snap/bin/firefox: symbolic link to /usr/bin/snap

$ file /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=fbd297b89a7b29cc2ab8dbd9a0135e0d31f9f046, stripped

$ file /snap/bin/firefox.geckodriver
/snap/bin/firefox.geckodriver: symbolic link to /usr/bin/snap

$ file /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/geckodriver
/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/geckodriver: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=1e8e38e794486bf4d9009b8a541b66cbbdaa5a00, with debug_info, not stripped

Since I did spend some time looking at the source code, I know the type is not verified using the bash utility file but is using pathlib's is_file function. Editing the script to also check is_symlink might be a fun challenge. That script should probably also specifically check for if the snap version of a browser is running.
$ file /usr/bin/snap
/usr/bin/snap: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=lJlrGZagTFQfotOw8hPQ/vEjk2Ktx9WH8rGhyIse-/VJS-j7kGZdr1_Lt919uh/cYxQiA18LNnhcSU3-jNg, stripped

It seems that the snap executable might use the name of the symbolic link to launch the correct program? Not entirely certain, that is interesting though. I wonder if that means the symlinks would be fine to run if they actually pointed to the correct files?

Message: Unable to obtain working Selenium Manager binary
can happen because debian/ubuntu do NOT package /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
On my Ubuntu 24.04, /usr/share/doc/python3-selenium/README.Debian says "At the time of writing [Selenium Manager] is not packaged for Debian."
That same file suggests to change all scripts to create a ChromeService directly. What I have done instead is to write a shell script which acts as a very basic replacement for selenium-manager:
$ cat /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager
#!/bin/sh
echo '{
        "result": {
         "browser_path": "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
         "driver_path": "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
        },
        "logs": []
      }'

(You can adapt so it selects firefox/geckodriver instead, obviously)
The alternative is obviously to install upstream selenium directly, to bypass this incomplete packaging job.
